# Grails 2.2.1 war fails to deploy

Tags: grails-2.2

Using grails 2.2.1 I created a war but it fails to depoly in my Tomcat 6 on linux and windows server.

At first I ran into this problem of "**org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/webapps/abby/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class**"

After a few hours of searching in stackovrerflow, and did this code to remove that error

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    // Servlet JAR conflicts with Tomcat's version. See: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9483
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30")
}
```

When that was resolved, I am stuck with this new error "**Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal"**

Datasource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            username="root"
            password=""
            url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.171.62:3306/cce_final"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            username="root"
            password=""
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cce_final?autoReconnect=true"
            properties {
                maxActive = 50
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 5
                initialSize = 5
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
                maxWait = 10000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenCentral()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }
}
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    // Servlet JAR conflicts with Tomcat's version. See: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9483
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30")
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30")
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
            <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Tomcat error log

```
17 May, 2013 9:24:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
17 May, 2013 9:24:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 58 more
17 May, 2013 9:24:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
17 May, 2013 9:24:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 57 more
```

Kindly help me in this regard. Have been trying to resolve it since days.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I solved a similar problem just by including a jar in my web-inf/lib directory which contained that class.  The jar was the apache batik library (an SVG processing library) - weird, but it seems to have fixed the problem (and my site deployed).  Try it with yours and see.

```
wget http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-ext/1.7/batik-ext-1.7.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem: A library (Jena TDB 1.0.0) had a dependency to xerces 2.11.0 and I got the same exception when deploying my grails application to tomcat. I solved the issue by adding xml-apis-1.4.01.jar to the lib folder of the application.

The tomcat-jar issue can be solved by changing the plugins closure in BuildConfig.groovy. The tomcat line should read as follows:

```
build ":tomcat:${grailsVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML-apis as below will make the error go away.

Use the below code in BuildConfig.groovy file inside the dependencies closure.

```
   compile (group:'org.apache.poi', name:'poi', version:'3.10-FINAL');
    compile (group:'org.apache.poi', name:'poi-ooxml', version:'3.10-FINAL')
    compile ('dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1')
    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.10-FINAL')
    compile('org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.0')
    runtime('xerces:xercesImpl:2.10.0')
    runtime ('xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01')
    runtime('xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0')
```

The Xerces:xercesImpl will have a wrong xml-api version in it. So, overriding it in the next line will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here 2 years later because you are getting the same error from:

```
grails run-app
```

To fix it, I added this compile time dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'
```

Then run:

```
grails clean
grails run-app
```

My Environment:

```
grails 2.5.4
java 8.77
ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```